# Launch file with Electron - New Window

Tags: electron

I cannot find documentation that outlines how I can create a new instance of an electron app window (via function).

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you mean `new BrowserWindow`?

Comment: @pergy I'm not sure. When the app is launched, I want the default behaviour to be new window.